# Profile page looks weird when you earn a new privilege

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web

So far, I've reproduced this with the Android 4.4.2 default browser and Google Chrome (55.0.2883.87 m).

This is, at least, present on https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/ and on https://security.stackexchange.com/.

On smaller screens (320px width), the profile looks incredibly weird.

This is how it looks like:

[image: Music Fans]

[image: Information Security]

And this is how it looks like on my phone:

[image: Information Security, real phone]

This is what the page looks like, when viewed on a desktop:

[image: Information Security - Desktop]

The page seems fine to me when you don't have the "You earned a new privilege" showing.

Comment: You are seeing the mobile view on... mobile devices. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean that the "You earned a new privilege" bit is all strange on smaller screens. I've shown how it looks like by using Google Chrome developer tools.